# Get Width of last line of multiline UILabel

Tags: iphone, objective-c, text, view, uilabel

I have a dynamic multi line UILabel and need to know the end of the text (X Coordinate) of the visible text (not the Label) so I can show something after the text.
Is this possible?

thank you

Comment: @leons..did u get any break through for this?...been struggling from couple of days on this..want to find the end of text in uilable so that i can add uibutton next to it...

Comment: pls share ur idea so that it can help me also..

Comment: you can take a look on a cool answer here, for me i benefit form it soo mush
http://stackoverflow.com/a/30351432/4498576

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll be able to have more control over the text layout with the CoreText framework. [Checkout the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005533):

There are also some nice open source things that already do a lot of the hard work for you, like: https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText

Comment: I started using CoreText and it's awesome :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know , the best solution for this is to use a UIWebView instead of a UILabel.
You just have to format the HTML for it to load and then add whatever you want to add after.

Example:

```
[webView loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body><font face=\"arial\" size=\"2\">%@</font><font face=\"arial\" size=\"1\"> %@</font></body></html>",text1 , text2] baseURL:nil];
```

If you want to keep trying with UILabel / UITextView /any UIView for that matter , I only know of a way to figure out the height properly : [myView sizeToFit]; And then get it's frame.

Hope this helps.

Regards,

George