# How to know the width of last line of label?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uilabel

In my app I have a label which text came from the server so I don't Know its width, and at the end of this label directly there should be an UIImage.

My problem is: I don't know how to position the image because of the non static width of the label text.

To be more clear, this is a snapshot form the design and how should it be:

[image: snapshot]

Any suggestion to solve this problem please?

Comment: I would suggest to use a font symbol. Lets say your string is attributed string, just add at the end ►
BLACK RIGHT-POINTING POINTER
Unicode: U+25BA, UTF-8: E2 96 BA. and make it blue and you are done.

Comment: can i color it ? 
as you can see it's blue

Comment: @JurajAntas my string came from server, so can i use your idea here ?
thanks so mush :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Width of last line of multiline UILabel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11189600/get-width-of-last-line-of-multiline-uilabel)

Comment: in your available textLabel Space put scrollView and inside scrollView put your text

Comment: It can be used with any string, doesn't matter from where it came from. Create attributed string, set colors and fonts for ranges and you are done. No expensive calculations at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Set the text of the `UILabel`
2. Get the width of this `UILabel` with `yourUILabel`.frame.width
3. Set the x coordinate of your `UIImage` at `yourUILabel.frame.width + emptySpace` like this

   ```
   var yourUIImageView:UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(x:PaddingFromLeft + yourUILabel.frame.width + emptySpace, y: yourYCoordinate, width: yourImageWidth, height : yourImageHeight))
   ```

Comment: Hi, What you mean PaddingFromLeft and emptySpace? What should i give Please.

Comment: what if the width of the last line is half the width of the entire label? If Im not wrong, the question wants to put the arrow at the end of labels last line.

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to insert your image directly on label doing this

```
var attachment = NSTextAttachment()
attachment.image = UIImage(named: "your_image_name")

var attributedString = NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment)
var labelString= NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame...")
labelString.appendAttributedString(attributedString)

yourUILabel.attributedText = labelString
```

Comment: thanks so mush! 
it's amazing :) 
but can i resize the attachment ? 
because the image appear to big

Comment: @eng_rawan: I'd say the best would be get the image with correct size for your scenario

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this problem. It's not the most beautiful code but it works. I return the words number from the last line of the label, from which I can calculate the width from where the text ends and the image starts (x,y) coordinates.

```
func lastWordInTitle(title: String) -> Int {
    var separateWords: [String] = []
    var sizeOfWords: [CGFloat] = []
    var wordsRemaining: Int = 0
    var wordsWidthInOneLine: CGFloat = 0

    let font = titleLabel.font
    let fontAttr = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: font]

    title.enumerateSubstrings(in: title.startIndex..<title.endIndex, options: .byWords) { (substring, _, _, _) in
        if let substring = substring {
            separateWords.append(substring) // number of words in label
            sizeOfWords.append(substring.size(withAttributes: fontAttr).width + 8) //size of each word + 8 for the space between them
        }
    }
    wordsRemaining = separateWords.count
    print("SSS wordsRemaining initial \(wordsRemaining)")
    var wordsToRemoveIndex = 0

    for index in 0..<separateWords.count {
        wordsWidthInOneLine += sizeOfWords[index]
        wordsToRemoveIndex += 1
        if wordsWidthInOneLine > titleLabel.frame.width {
            if index == separateWords.count - 1  {
                wordsRemaining -= wordsToRemoveIndex
                return 1
            } else {
                wordsRemaining -= wordsToRemoveIndex - 1 == 0 ? 1 : wordsToRemoveIndex - 1
                wordsToRemoveIndex = 0
                wordsWidthInOneLine = 0
                wordsWidthInOneLine = sizeOfWords[index]

            }
        } else if wordsWidthInOneLine < titleLabel.frame.width && index == separateWords.count - 1 {
            let reversedSeparateWordsSize = Array(sizeOfWords.reversed())
            var width: CGFloat = 0
            for index in 0..<wordsRemaining {
                width += reversedSeparateWordsSize[index]
            }
            if width > titleLabel.frame.width {
                return wordsRemaining - 1
            }
            return wordsRemaining
        }
    }

    return wordsRemaining
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It, actually, depends...

You might want to use `sizeToFit` or `sizeThatFits` methods.

Comment: sizeToFit resizes the label. Its width is the width of the string.
sizeThatFits returns the same size without resizing the label.
In both cases, check the width param and that will be the width of the string.